# how to extract a ip address from command result and store result in a variable

Tags: bash, sh, gcloud

How to extract the IP address of the output of the `gcloud` command mentioned bellow?

The goal is to extract the IP_ADRESS where  TARGET contains `targetPools` and store it in a variable.

```
$ gcloud compute forwarding-rules list
>output:

NAME: abc
REGION: us
IP_ADDRESS: 00.000.000.000
IP_PROTOCOL: abc
TARGET: us/backendServices/abc

NAME: efg
REGION: us
IP_ADDRESS: 11.111.111.111
IP_PROTOCOL: efg
TARGET: us/targetPools/efg
```

desired output:

```
IP="11.111.111.111"
```

my attempt:

```
IP=$(gcloud compute forwarding-rules list | grep "IP_ADDRESS")
```

it doesn't work bc it need to

1. get the one with TARGET contains `targetPools`
2. extract the IP_ADRESS
3. store in local variable to be used

But not sure how to do this, any hints?

Comment: `gcloud ... 2>&1 | grep -FB2 'TARGET: us/targetPools/efg' | head -n1 | sed 's/^.*: *//'`

Comment: it worked, thanks @Jetchisel.
please post as the answer explaining the command and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your given input, you could chain a few commands with pipes. That means there is always one line of text/string in between `TARGET` and `IP_ADDRESS`.

```
gcloud ... 2>&1 | grep -FB2 'TARGET: us/targetPools/efg' | head -n1 | sed 's/^.*: *//'
```

---

You could do without the `head`, something like

```
gcloud ... 2>&1 | grep -FB2 'TARGET: us/targetPools/efg' | sed 's/^.*: *//;q'
```

---

Some code explanation.

- `2>&1` Is a form of shell redirection, it is there to capture`stderr` and `stdout`.
- `-FB2` is a shorthand for `-F` `-B 2`

  - See `grep --help | grep -- -B`
  - See `grep --help | grep -- -F`
- `sed 's/^.*: *//'`

  - `^` Is what they call an anchor, it means from the start.
  - `.*` Means zero or more character/string.

    - `.` Will match a single string/character
    - `*` Is what they call a quantifier, will match zero or more character string
  - `:` Is a literal `:` in this context
  - `*` Will match a space, (zero or more)
  - `//` Remove what ever is/was matched by the pattern.
  - `q` means quit, without it `sed` will print/output all the lines that was matched by `grep`

Comment: Hi @Jetchisel, would you be able to explain what `grep -FB2` does?  Also explain a little bit what the `sed regular expression` is doing?   Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
gcloud ... 2>&1 | awk -F: 'BEGIN {RS=""} $10 ~ /targetPools/ {print $6}'
```